# Python3 - Splitting a string and keeping the end part only

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have the below string;

```
PID: N9K-C92160YC-X      ,  VID: V01 ,  SN: FDO211410AK
```

I'm trying to print out two parts, the first being "N9K-C92160YC-X" and the second being "FDO211410AK"

I've managed to get the PID by doing;

```py
modeltype = net_connect.send_command('sh inv | i Chassis next 1 | i PID').split("  ")[0]]
print(modeltype)
```

which gives me:

```
PID: N9K-C92160YC-X
```

I can't figure how to split and keep just the SN though;

```py
serialnumber = net_connect.send_command('sh inv | i Chassis next 1 | i PID').split("SN:")[0]
print(serialnumber)
```

Output:

```
PID: N9K-C92160YC-X      ,  VID: V01 ,
```

Comment: `serialnumber = net_connect.send_command('sh inv | i Chassis next 1 | i PID').split("SN:")[1]` ?

Comment: use `[-1]` to get last element

Comment: Your code is exactly one byte away from the correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no distinct format which entries are contained within the string (PID, VID, SN or others), you should use regular expressions to extract the required information(s):

```
import re

str = "PID: N9K-C92160YC-X      ,  VID: V01 ,  SN: FDO211410AK"

pid = re.search(r"PID: ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)", str).group(1)
print(pid)
# N9K-C92160YC-X

sn = re.search(r"SN: ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)", str).group(1)
print(sn)
# FDO211410AK
```

Answer (score 3):

Split on whitespace and then access the second and last element from the resulting array:

```
str = "PID: N9K-C92160YC-X      ,  VID: V01 ,  SN: FDO211410AK"
parts = re.split(r'\s+', str)
print(parts[1])
print(parts[-1])
```

This prints:

```
N9K-C92160YC-X
FDO211410AK
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your text is structured so giving proper names would be useful:

```
def parts(s, separator):
    return [e.strip() for e in s.split(separator)]

s = "PID: N9K-C92160YC-X      ,  VID: V01 ,  SN: FDO211410AK" 
pid, vid, sn = parts(s, ",")
pid_key, pid_value = parts(pid, ":")
sn_key, sn_value = parts(sn, ":")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split it on space and strip excess spaces.

```
text = "PID: N9K-C92160YC-X      ,  VID: V01 ,  SN: FDO211410AK"
parts = [txt.strip() for txt in text.split()]
print(parts[1], parts[-1])
```

Comment: This prints `PID: N9K-C92160YC-X SN: FDO211410AK` but the OP wants `N9K-C92160YC-X FDO211410AK`

Comment: Thanks. Modified the code now to display "N9K-C92160YC-X FDO211410AK"